# Ornstein Uhlenbeck process bounded exponential expectation

Tags: markov, gaussian-process, stochastic-process

I found the following statement but can't figure out how to show it: Let

```
Y_t = -k Y_t dt + a dt + dW_t
```

be an Ornstein Uhlenbeck process, where `k > 0, a \in R, W` is Brownian motion.
Then it is an ergodic Gauss-Markov process, so there exists a `\beta > 0` such that

```
sup_{t \geq 0} E(e^{\beta Y_t^2}) < \infty.
```

I can't explain why this should be true. can someone help me?

I tried to calculate

```
E(e^{\beta X_t^2})
```

for some Gaussian variable `X_t` directly, but this is not a finite value...

Comment: This question is not about programming. For math questions there exists math.stackexchange.com. For math research-level questions (which this is not) there is mathoverflow.net